# a name for a boy, boy's name, boy name

Tags: grammar, possessives

Which of the following phrases are grammatically correct, meaning "a name for a boy"?

> 1. A boy's name.
> 2. A boys' name.
> 3. A boy name.
> 4. A boys name.

Any response would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd say that for a lot of places where some languages use "a name for a boy", English use "masculine (or male) given name". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:English_masculine_given_names

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We commonly write "a boy's name". "Boy's" is a singular possessive. It is a name for one boy.

You could talk about "boys' names", plural. That is, names for many boys.

"A boys' name" is grammatically valid but almost never used in practice. "Boys'" is a plural possessive but "name" is singular, so you would be referring to one name used by many boys. That's certainly logically possible. There are many boys named "John", so we could say "John is a name used by many boys. John is a boys' name." But we just don't normally write this. We still say "boy's name". I suppose you could say we're thinking of one boy at a time. Even if they have a common name, we think of each boy as having his own "copy" of the name. It would be different if it was a single item that they really shared. Like "We have one gym for boys and another gym for girls. This is the boys' gym."

"Boy name" is often used in informal speech, but not in formal speech or writing. One could argue that it is valid: using a noun as an adjective, like "car part". But we just don't do that.

"Boys name" is thus doubly a problem. There's the singular vs plural problem that I discussed with "boys' name", plus the noun vs adjective problem.

So to put it briefly: Use "boy's name".

Comment: Great answer and examples. Though politically suspect, we could add "We have names for girls and names for boys; 'Alan' is a boys' name."

Comment: @Strawberry: Hmm. By that token, "We have names for men and names for women; 'Alan' is a **men's** name." That certainly doesn't work for me - it still has to be **...is a man's name.**

Comment: An exception could be something like "All those boys have the same name, and John is the boys' name."

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't mean that the plural possessive is appropriate if preceded by a sentence sounding like my example. What I was trying to say is that a plural possessive makes sense when we are talking about one thing jointly owned by multiple people. But as I said, in the case of names, we tend to think of each person as having his own "copy" of the name.

Comment: "We just don't do that".  Him: I'm going to call my new puppy "Killer".  Her: Such a typical boy name - what's wrong with Fido?
@Barmar your exception works due to the substitution of 'the' for 'a'.

Comment: @mcalex Sorry, I see my paragraph on that is a bit muddled. I was trying to say, "'Boy name' is commonly used in informal speech, but not in formal writing." By "we just don't do that" I mean, we don't do it in formal writing.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 9):

> A boy's name

Perfectly grammatical and idiomatic. Refers to the name of a specific boy or a name that could be used for a boy.

> A boys' name

Perfectly grammatical and idiomatic.  Refers to a name that is commonly used for boys.

> A boy name

This is probably the most controversial of the list. In my experience, "boy" is not uncommonly used as an adjective, e.g. "boy toy".  So I would say this is fine but informal and not as common as "a boy's name".  Google's Ngrams shows it as [about 1/10th as common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20boy%27s%20name%2Ca%20boy%20name&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20boy%20%27s%20name%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20boy%20name%3B%2Cc0)

> A boys name

Grammatically incorrect and non-idiomatic.  "Boys" is a plural noun.

Comment: Is "boys' name" plural? I think the plural form is "boys' names", isn't it?

Comment: @shapoor I don't understand your question.  You seem to be repeating what I said

Comment: I mean "boys' name" isn't plural. It's a name for boys. So it is singular.

Comment: @shapoor Hmm. I see what you're getting at. Have to think about that for a second

Comment: @shapoor You are correct.  Edited my answer to reflect that.  What do you think of how I have the answer worded now?

Comment: why is the last one incorrect? I mean "boys name" isn't plural too. A name for boys, am I right? Here "boys" functions as an adjective.

Comment: IDK if anyone else would read it this way or not, but "a boy name" implies that the name itself is a young male, not that the name typically refers to a young male.

Comment: I think "a boy name" is much more common when we're discussing the generic.  E.g. "Sue is a girl name, not a boy name, even if there was a song about a boy named Sue": https://genius.com/Johnny-cash-a-boy-named-sue-lyrics

Comment: It's hard to find anything that's always grammatically incorrect in English. You can usually find a special case where it's correct. In addition to a plural noun, Boys is also a surname. So Boys name is correct in that case. Just getting in my pedantic nitpick for the week.

Answer (score 8):

[Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20a%20boys%20name%2Cis%20a%20boy%27s%20name%2Cis%20a%20boys%27%20name%2Cis%20a%20boy%20name&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20boy%20%27s%20name%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20boy%20's%20name%3B%2Cc0) the relevant usage chart...

[image]

Note that in this *specific* case, the difference is purely one of ***orthography*** for the ***boys, boy's, boys'*** choices (not reflected in real ***spoken*** language), so you shouldn't be surprised if you sometimes encounter incorrectly ***written*** forms.

But all native speakers know perfectly well that no-one ever says *X is a **men** name* (and *a **man** name* is extremely unlikely). And since there's no such word as ***mans*** in English, that leaves *X is a **man's** name* as the only credible orthography - then it's easy to apply the same principle to *X is a **boy's** name*.

Comment: Do you mean all of them are grammatically correct?

Comment: Certainly not! I said *X is a man's name* is ***the only credible orthography*** - that's to say all other alternatives are so badly wrong that they're not even ***credible*** (no native speaker would believe them to be valid). The whole point of my answer was to show that this is blindingly obvious if we consider *a **man's** name* (it's not so easy with *a **boy's** name* because there's no difference between singular/plural possessive written and spoken forms). And I put a red circle round the "not found" NGram text for the invalid versions.

Answer (score 5):

They're not really sentences: they're phrases.

1) is the only correct one:

> Is Sixtus a boy's name?

But we also say *a name for a boy* (as you did in your question) in certain contexts:

> Naming girls is easy, but it's difficult to think of a name for a boy.

*Boys'* is the possessive of a *plural* noun, so *a boys' . . .* doesn't make sense.

> Boys' names like Peter and Matthew are found in the Bible.

*A boy name* is not idiomatic.

Comment: I disagree about the last one.  "a boy name" is somewhat common informally.  e.g. "You named your daughter Kevin? That's a boy name"

Comment: @Kevin While writing my answer I did look for that usage. On Lexico. It isn't there under 'boy' OR if you search for the phrase (https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&dictionary=en&query=boy+name). I'm familiar with such expressions as 'boy racer' 'boy things', 'boy band' etc, but have never heard "A boy name".